# When to create new RDS Instance vs new database?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have two AWS RDS Postgres Instances. Sometimes I create new instances for applications that are (very) vaguely related to other applications. Which always leads me to the question; should I just create a new database in an existing instance or keep things separate and create a new instance instead?

Comment: Do the applications make intensive use of the database server (shared vs separate server)? Are there any situations where you would want to share information between these logical databases (schema vs database)? Do they have different storage requirements (speed, capacity)? Are backup requirements different? Are uptime requirements different (single node vs multi-AZ)? Do different teams manage the different databases (access permissions, responsibilities)? How important is cost for you?

Comment: The databases don't make intensive use of the serve. Yes, there **might** be situations in which I would want to share information between these logical databases. There are no significant differences in storage requirements or capacity. Uptime requirements are essentially the same. No, team is small so they all have access to the databases. Cost is absolutely crucial to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you **use the same database server** (Amazon RDS instance).

You can logically separate the data via either:

- `CREATE DATABASE`: Full logical separation. You login to one database and never see the other one. *OR*
- `CREATE SCHEMA`: Data is kept separate, but can be referenced from the other. Quite common for staging areas, such as doing ETL in a Staging Schema, then publishing to a Production Schema.

From your description, I'd say that `CREATE DATABASE` would be appropriate.

The benefit is that you only need to manage one database and there is little impact on cost unless you need to increase the size of the database instance to handle the higher load (but it would still be cheaper than running two separate databases).

Just keep an eye on the CloudWatch metrics to be sure that the database is handling the increased load correctly.

Normally, the biggest reason for using a different server is because they are owned/managed by different teams. However, in your situation the same team seems to 'own' both data stores, so that wouldn't be an issue.